# Fetch list of all items having same flag from custom arraylist

Tags: java, android, arraylist

1) ArrayList of custom Objects Example:: `ArrayList<CustomModel>` **arrayList**.
2) CustomModel having boolean flag and name of person.
3) **arrayList** has total 10 elements from that 4 items has **true** boolean flag and remaining 6 has **false** flag.

4) Now I wanted that:: new ArrayList of all the items which having **true** flag.

*Note:* without using for and if loop it is possible?

Comment: How are you supposed to iterate through an array without a loop?

Comment: can you use other types of loops other than a for loop?

Comment: How do you create the initial list? Maybe you can create 2 lists straight away an get rid of the boolean?

Comment: We can get total count of same occurrences from ArrayList using,  int occurrences = Collections.frequency(arrayList, new CustomModel(true)");  it will return total count of  items having **true** flag i.e. 4, But I want all the data of that 4 occurrences  in the form of same custom array list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using JAVA 8 you can use streams.

**NOTE** : streams uses iterators and loops internally.

```
ArrayList<CustomModel> arrayList =
          youArrayList.stream().filter(o -> o.isTrue()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

here `o` is your `CustomModel` so you need to call the specific function on which you want to filter.

Comment: thank you for the solution. But if is there is one more Custom Object class under CustomModel and want to check flag with it then  (Example::  `ArrayList<CustomModel> arrayList =
                myArrayList.stream().filter(o -> o.ChildModel.isTrueFlag.collect(Collectors.toList());`)

Comment: you can add the getter for the child class. and use it like `o.getChildClass().isTrue()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can not get rid of loops as that will help you to iterate through list, but there is an easy and fast way to do that. Please find the code below:

```
arrayList.parallerStream().filter(p->p.flag).collect(Collectors.toList())
```